# JIRA : default date class override

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api

We are trying to change JIRA default display dates to shamsi/jalali Date (Persian date).

Is it possible to write a plugin to override the default date format display of JIRA? How?

Comment: Did you check [this out](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/198204/jalali-calendar-for-jira)?

Comment: its just for forms ... we wanted to override date rendering of jira @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc

Comment: Did you check this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/__date-and-time-formats-686860811.html